# If $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then $c\cdot f(x)$ is also integrable and $\int_a^b c\cdot f(x) dx=c\cdot \int_a^b f(x) dx$

Tags: integration, proof-verification

I proved the first part of this theorem which says that $c\cdot f(x)$ is integrable,but how to prove that $\int_a^b c\cdot f(x) dx=c\cdot \int_a^b f(x) dx$?
Maybe it provides a bit help if i tell how i proved the first part.
Let $c\neq 0$.Then for all $\epsilon$,also for ${\epsilon \over |c|}$  exists a $P$ partition such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<{\epsilon \over |c|}$.
$U(c\cdot f,P)-L(c\cdot f,P)=c\cdot [U(f,P)-L(f,P)]$ if $c>0$
$U(c\cdot f,P)-L(c\cdot f,P)=c\cdot [L(f,P)-U(f,P)]$ if $c<0$
so its $=|c|[U(f,P)-L(f,P)]<|c|\cdot {\epsilon \over |c|}=\epsilon$.From which comes that $c\cdot f(x)$ is integrable.

Comment: It seems you've shown $U(cf,P)=cU(f,P)$ for any partition $P$. Your result follows from this (since you've shown $cf$ is integrable).

Comment: ok $U(c\cdot f,P)-L(c\cdot f,P)=|c|[U(f,P)-L(f,P)]<\epsilon$  but how comes from this what you said?(the equation)

Comment: Yes, you've already done that. This shows $cf$ is integrable, so the integral is the limit of upper sums as the mesh size of the partitions tend to zero. Use the equality above to show $\int_a^b cf(x)\,dx=c\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$:  $$\int_a^b cf(x)\,dx =\lim_{\Vert P\Vert\rightarrow 0} U(cf,P)=c\lim_{\Vert P\Vert\rightarrow 0} U(f,P)=c\int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Thanks,i think i see it now.